# Modifying get_author_posts_url() in Wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm in a bit of a pickle and I'm not sure how to get out of it. Not sure if this is a known Wordpress multisite bug or not or the way the multisite i am working on was setup. The kind of issue I am having is similar to this one http://www.feedmeastraycat.net/2011/10/04/wp-get_author_posts_url-in-mu-with-sub-directories/

By the way, I've just inherited this project and trying to 'unravel' the spaghetti.

The links created by `get_author_posts_url()` in theme functions file to generate the link for the author end up having an extra "/blog" in front of them and they should not have it there. Within the child sites, the get_author_posts_url() generated links are all ok and do not contain the "/blog" in the URL string.

Here is the website http://blogs.slq.qld.gov.au/.
When you click on an author link from the feature post tiles, you get an error 404 page returned. If you go into on of the child blogs - it does not happen.

Just trying to figure out a way to remove the "/blog" from the link string data generated by `get_author_posts_url()`

i.e. make http://blogs.slq.qld.gov.au/business-intelligence/blog/author/grailadmin/

BECOME....

http://blogs.slq.qld.gov.au/business-intelligence/author/grailadmin/

Comment: Would you consider to post your question on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For sure. Did not know of its existence actually!

Comment: I posted it in wordpress stackexchange but due to my low rating there (as I just joined) I was unable to put the full question explanation there http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202930/modifying-get-author-posts-url-in-wordpress-multisite