# Using .HTACCESS file to do 301 redirects in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Have inherited a WordPress multisite that I did not build (stating the obvious here). Anyway. The front page is made up of 'tiles' which display a range of posts' content (featured image, metadata, title, excerpt).

Anyway, the link on the author goes to an error 404 page on the top level of the multi site but works within each child site. Issues is that the link has an extra '/blog' in the link. More details about that issue here [Modifying get_author_posts_url() in Wordpress multisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623040/modifying-get-author-posts-url-in-wordpress-multisite?noredirect=1#comment53096360_32623040)

Anyway, I am very limited in my PHP skills so I thought I might be able to circumvent the issue with a .htaccess 301 redirection but so far it is not working.

I edited the .htaccess file on the root level of the multi site like so (first three lines are my edits):

```
#Domain Specific Redirects
redirect 301 http://blog2.slq.qld.gov.au/jol/blog/author/jrbeaumont/ http://blog2.slq.qld.gov.au/jol/author/jrbeaumont/

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200

# END WordPress
```

There are many more redirects to do but for whatever reason, this just is not working for me. Is there something that I am doing wrong or is this kind of thing just simply not possible?

Note: I have a strong feeling that this could be better managed with a rewrite rule that would remove the '/blog' from the URL but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this easily. I just did not understand .htaccess redirects that well. I found a good source of information here https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file and it was much more clearer to me about performing redirects. Never should have used 301 in the first place, nor should I have used the full absolute path for the reference URL.

Solution as follows:

```
#Domain Specific Redirects
redirect /jol/blog/author/jrbeaumont/ http://blog2.slq.qld.gov.au/jol/author/jrbeaumont/
```

Not sure of how to create a rule for it, but will keep exploring.